# Geometric row/column Sum Pattern in any numerical calculator

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, geometry, calculator

By random luck I found this intriguing geometric pattern of summing in the numerical keypad. I'm curious if it is related to the base 10 system or how the numerical keypad was arranged, but couldn't find any info on the internet outside some fringe websites.

Let me explain. You start by summing the first row with the reverse of it like,

123+321=444

Then noticed that 444*2 is 888 which is equal of the first column summed with with its reverse,

147+741=888

Then you have 444*2.5 which is the sum of the diagonals, like

753+357=159+951=1110

It just goes on

444*3=1332=369+963

444*4=1776=789+987

Also some other patterns that matches the multiples of 444

111+333=444

111+777=888

444+666=111+999=333+777=1110

333+999=1332

777+999=1776

111+333+777+999=444*5=2220

Is there any mathematical explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing is that the keys in a straight line are in arithmetic progression.  The three numbers are of the form $a,a+d,a+2d$.  When you reverse this sequence and add, youu get $2a+2d,2a+2d,2a+2d$.  That explains why you get three digits the same.  For the top row you have $a=1,d=1$ so $2a+2d=4$, which is why you get $444$.  For the left column you have $a=1,d=3$ so $2a+2d=8$ and you get $888$.  One diagonal has $a=3,d=2$ and the other has $a=1,d=4$, both of which give $2a+2d=10$

Comment: thanks, that makes sense.